# Shuffling the Row data in Stack-wise manner in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am facing a problem in SQL Server for performing STACK like operation in my table, such given below:

**INPUT:**

```
    Id      Name               CanNo
-------------------------------------
    2892    HIDBO-121-D-14-d      4
    2891    HIDBO-121-D-14-c      3
    2890    HIDBO-121-D-14-b      2
    2889    HIDBO-121-D-14-a      1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    Id      Name               CanNo     PreviousID
---------------------------------------------------
    2892    HIDBO-121-D-14-b    2         ______
    2891    HIDBO-121-D-14-d    4         ______
    2890    HIDBO-121-D-14-c    3         ______
    2889    HIDBO-121-D-14-a    1         ______
```

I am using this query to achieve above given OUTPUT:

```
DECLARE @LocId=2890
DECLARE @k=1
DECLARE @i=2
DECLARE @j=4

WHILE (@i < @j)
BEGIN
    UPDATE T1.Id = T2.Id
    FROM [@UNE_STLOCDT] T1 
    JOIN #temp T2 ON (T1.Id = (@LocId+@K) AND T2.Id= (@LocId+(@K-1)))
                  OR (T1.Id = (@LocId+(@K-1)) AND T2.Id= (@LocId+@K))

    SET @i = @i + 1
    SET @K = @K + 1
END
```

I am able to shuffle this but cannot be able to store previous id (before shuffling) for future reference.

Please help me.

Comment: (1) what is a "stacking" operation? Do you mean ordering descending by `CanNo`? (2) what is your expected output?

Comment: mean if I choose a particular ID it will be placed at top.